# Ignite taking Too much time to add data to Cache

Tags: spring-boot, ignite, apacheignite

I am trying to put data in Ignite Cache and it was taking too much time and making my process much slow.
I have an Ignite Cache of type `IgniteCache<Integer,List<Integer>>` and adding data to cache taking too much time. I am using 4 nodes in cluster.

How to reduce its time and make the processing fast?

Comment: This question doesn't seem actionable at the moment, let's try to improve it. Could you please elaborate what do you mean by slow, what's the latency? Is it average time, or some spikes, or maybe some percentile metric? How much data do you have uploaded? What the volume of the mutation operations? Do you have native persistence enabled, if yes, what are your disks? What's the size of your `List<Integer>` objects? What cache configuration do you have, do you use transactions? What's your environment, is it a cloud environment?

Comment: yes its a cloud environment and its the total amount of time to load data in cache and native persistance is enabled

Comment: Am I correct that "total amount of time to load data" means it's about throughput, not latency? Do you have logs for the period? What data region and cache configurations do you use? What APIs are used for the ingestion, is it data streamer?